Group by @reportId and @taskName in AWS Cloudwatch and find duration by logs
My Cloudwatch logs from Django app deployed via Zappa to AWS Lambdas are of the following format:
  {
    taskName: foo.bar,
    @requestId: 98ccca67-46db-4793-9a62-412f9dc60ed5  
  }

  {
    @billedDuration: 24723.0, 
    @duration: 24722.88,
    @maxMemoryUsed: 2.49E8,
    @requestId: 98ccca67-46db-4793-9a62-412f9dc60ed5,
    @type: REPORT
  }

Now I want to create a cloudwatch dashboard or maybe just cloudwatch log insights query, so that I can find how long each task took over time (bin by mins/hours/days/months etc.)
example1: foo.bar - avg duration over last 1 hour is 30 seconds
example2: foo.baz - avg duration over last 1 hour is 20 seconds

and so on. The key here is reportId which is the next log and has the duration, original message has the requestId but not the duration. So we need to group by or find neighbouring reportId.
I tried GPT and other resources but couldn't get it working, thanks in advance :)

CloudWatch has two limitations

it does not have joins
it does not allow to aggregate twice, i.e. you cannot have two |stats clauses in the query

Combined, these two issues make your query impossible to write.

Why 2nd limitation is important in this context? Because you can emulate join using aggregation, e.g.
stats max(taskName) as _taskName, max(@duration) as _duration by @requestId

^ this way you join two records into single presentation.
To build statistics by taskName you would write something like
stats max(taskName) as _taskName, max(@duration) as _duration by @requestId
| stats avg(_duration) as avg_duration by _taskName

but it means two stats clauses within single query and this is not allowed.

thanks for your help @alexander Pavlov
